# How can I change a Windows code page in Python?

Tags: python, codepages

Consider:

```
>>> a = os.popen('chcp 65001')
>>> a.read()
'Active code page: 65001\n'
>>> a.close()
>>> a = os.popen('chcp')
>>> a.read()
'Active code page: 437\n'
>>> a.close()
```

After I set the code page to [65001](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), the next time I call [CHCP](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) it should say the active code page is 65001, not 437.  I tried this in the Windows command prompt and it worked.

Why doesn't it work through Python code?

Comment: Why are you trying to change the code page in python instead of using [string encodings](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)?

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that every time you call `os.popen` you are spawning a new process.  Try opening up two `cmd.exe` sessions and running `chcp 65001` in one and `chcp` in the other—that's what you are doing here in your Python code.

One thing to note:  all of the [`popen*()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.popen) calls are deprecated as of Python 2.6.  The new module to use is the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module.